# How to convert perl modules to mod_perl handlers?

Tags: perl, handler, mod-perl, mod-perl2

I have some perl modules which are intergreted in a cgi script which runs on a web server. How can I simply convert these modules to a mod_perl handler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is for mod_perl to make your code cached/faster, then...

Just add the following to your Apache host configuration:

```
Alias               /cgi-bin/ /path/to/your/cgi/script/folder
PerlRequire         /path/to/startup-script.pl
<Files ~ (\.cgi)>
  Options           +ExecCGI
  SetHandler        perl-script
  PerlHandler       ModPerl::Registry
  PerlSendHeader    On
</Files>
```

In `startup-script.pl` set up your include path (if needed) with `use lib`.

Then you can just use `CGI::Simple` as before.

Comment: Thanks vor your answer. Yes, I Want to run it a little bit faster. The problem is that I work with Sub::WrapPackages to run something before and after each method.

Comment: Using `mod_perl` won't speed up wrapped routines. It really only pre-loads & pre-compiles. You don't get much appreciable run-time speed up.